# Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG , string is too long

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm working with 3D models in javascript and I'm trying to send a json file of the polygons from the model as a string, but gets `Error: spawn ENAMETOOLONG`
everytime.

Here is my code:

```js
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
xmlhttp.open("POST", url, false);
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
xmlhttp.send(payload);

let response = JSON.stringify(xmlhttp.responseText);
response = response.replace(/\}|\{|\\r\\n|\\/g,"");
response = response.trim();
console.log(response);

return response;
```

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Which Platform are you using as the back-end (NodeJS or PHP ...)

I would not be unable to answer this **without knowing the back-end platform** as there are many possibilities. Even your Operating System could apply limitations...

So, I request you to provide the above Information so that I could help you better!

**If you are using NodeJS and Express with BodyParser**,
Increase the BodyParser Limits and the Parameter Count to proceed without any issue!

```
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "15mb" })); //Whatever size you feel you require
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  limit: "15mb",
  extended: true,
  parameterLimit: 100000, //Amount of parameters you feel is required
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid searching in .gitignore'd files by expanding the search viewlet details and toggling the "Use Ignore Files" button
[image]